# How IEnumerable Can Store Data

Tags: c#, ienumerable, iqueryable

How an Interface like IEnumerable or IQuerable can store data into itself?
or for example where this **Tables** go on `IQueryable?
and How can I have an Interface like that for myself  ?

```
public Interface IMyNumerator<T>  
{

}

IMyNumerator<int> mynumbers;
```

how can I fill **mynumbers** with some Int values ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interfaces themselves do not contain data. Although you may see IEnumerable as a type when using a collection, the underlying object is always of a specific type implementing this interface.

The object actually containing your data may be of any type implementing that interface.
Please refer to:

- [IEnumerable interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [List implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

And if you would like to implement your own version of IEnumerable, inherit from the interface . Try searching for "A Beginners Tutorial on Implementing IEnumerable" on codeproject ;-)

Comment: Thank for your links; I'm searching about it

Comment: Well, I would have loved to give you the link, but I just started to actively contribute here after leeching for waaay too long ;-)
BTW.... link I found was: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/474678/A-Beginners-Tutorial-on-Implementing-IEnumerable-I

Comment: Actually **System.Linq** was Interested for me; if you remove it; you no longer can use List Functions for IEnumerable. due to extensions !!!. I got it 80% ; I'm going to research more; Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces define, well interfaces.

You can see it as defining a Contract, that explains how to work with a specific concept. Behind the interface is an actual Implementation, for example a Database Connection.

> In computer science, an interface is the point of interaction with software

To make it a bit more simple, consider this in the hardware world.

USB defines an interface to things, it has a specific shape so it can go into a specific plug, and it has "protocols" of how to talk with a USB device.

An behind this "interface" you can have, just about any device. Fx. a camera or a storage device.

Comment: I usually use the phrase "contract". As in, the interface defines a contract that you sign up to when you use it. How the contract is fulfilled (the implementation) shouldn't really matter.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth That was the word I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

An interface never stores data. An implementation does. Whenever your code sees an object of type `IEnumerable`, its actual dynamic type is something else, like a `ListIterator` or so. If you want to have your own type implement `IEnumerable` you can just do that. Usually, you'll have an embedded (private) class that implements the enumerator for a collection, though.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is a very confusing question but I'll try anyway.

`IEnumerable` is an Interface that only describes public methods / properties, it does not describe how data is stored.

The implementer of this interface is responsible to store the data and can do so in any structure that suits the need.

You can have an interface like that by yourself by either implemented it or defining another interface that you use.